# reflect on class for certain attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

How can I write reflection code that goes through my project and looks for classes with special attribute and able to collection 2 pieces of information: ClassName.PropertyName  and string that is being passed into ResourceManager.GetValue inside the property. My code is as follows. Please help. Thanks

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> mydictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        mydictionary = ParseAllClassesWithAttribute("MyAttribute");

        Assert.AreEqual(mydictionary["MyClass.FirstNameIsRequired"].ToString(), "First Name is Required");


    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> ParseAllClassesWithAttribute(string p)
    {
        Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // use reflection to go through the class that is decorated by attribute MyAttribute
        // and is able to extract ClassName.PropertyName along with what is Inside
        // GetValue method parameter.
        // In the following I am artificially populating the dictionary object.

        dictionary.Add("MyClass.FirstNameIsRequired", "First Name is Required");
        return dictionary;
    }



     [MyAttribute]
     public class MyClass
        {
            public string FirstNameIsRequired
            {
                get
                {
                    return ResourceManager.GetValue("First Name is required");
                }
            }
        }

        public static class ResourceManager
        {
            public static string GetValue(string key)
            {
                return String.Format("some value from the database based on key {0}",key);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Here's a great resource (via my Google-Fu): http://oreilly.com/catalog/progcsharp/chapter/ch18.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection can't extract the `"First Name is Required"` value, unless you take the IL bytes and parse them.  Here's one potential solution:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string TheString { get; private set; }
    public MyAttribute(string theString)
    {
        this.TheString = theString;
    }
}

const string FirstNameIsRequiredThing = "First Name is required";
[MyAttribute(FirstNameIsRequiredThing)]
public string FirstNameIsRequired
{
    get
    {
        return ResourceManager.GetValue(FirstNameIsRequiredThing);
    }
}
```

Now you can read all properties with `MyAttribute` and see the expected values. (if you have trouble with this part, be sure to follow the advice of the comments on your question)